# PHP PDO Select ANY value does not return anything

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
$sql = $baglanti->prepare("
    SELECT inv_id, item_id
    FROM inventory
    WHERE item_id = ANY (
        SELECT item_id
        FROM inventory
        WHERE :uzunwhere
    ) AND item_color =  ANY (
        SELECT item_color
        FROM inventory
        WHERE :uzunwhere
    ) AND item_quality =  ANY (
        SELECT item_quality
        FROM inventory
        WHERE :uzunwhere
    ) AND item_location = :loc
    AND (character_id = :cid OR :cid = :owner)
");

$sql->execute(array(
    ':uzunwhere' => $whereKosul,
    ':loc' => $mekanid,
    ':cid' => $charID,
    ':owner' => $ishome['place_ownerID']
));
$bulunanlar = $sql->fetchAll(/*PDO::FETCH_ASSOC*/);
$sayi = $sql->rowCount();
echo $sayi;
```

When i catch the result, $sayi shows me 0. I am not sure about that is there any query syntax like that "ANY" in PHP?

I also tried this code in MySQL workbench via query runner. There is no problem in there.

`$uzunWhere` is a variable which can be changeable with my if statement above the code. Here is the example:

```
$uzunWhere = "inv_id = 111 OR inv_id = 95"
```

Comment: [Query parts you can bind](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#bindable)

Answer (score 0):

SQL parameters cannot be expressions. Use a parameter in place of a **single scalar value** like a numeric constant, a quoted string constant, or a date constant.

You cannot use a parameter for any other part of the query, like an expression, or a table or column identifier, or an SQL keyword, or a list of values (unless you use a separate parameter per value in the list).

For your `$uzunWhere` variable, you have to interpolate it into the string without using a query parameter.

```
$sql = $baglanti->prepare("
    SELECT inv_id, item_id
    FROM inventory
    WHERE item_id = ANY (
        SELECT item_id
        FROM inventory
        WHERE $uzunWhere
    ) AND item_color =  ANY (
        SELECT item_color
        FROM inventory
        WHERE $uzunWhere
    ) AND item_quality =  ANY (
        SELECT item_quality
        FROM inventory
        WHERE $uzunWhere
    ) AND item_location = :loc
    AND (character_id = :cid OR :cid = :owner)
");
```

This means you must take other precautions in the code that defines `$uzunWhere`, to make sure it does not introduce SQL injection risks.